# Can I find out two numbers if I know their difference and XOR?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that

$a = x \oplus y$  where $\oplus $ is the exclusive or (xor)

$b = x - y $ where $ x > y $

Can I find $x$ & $y$?

Both x & y are positive integers.

Comment: How do you define $\oplus$?  For example, what is $0\oplus -1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider, for instance, what happens if $y$ is even and $x = y+1$. Then both the difference and the xor is equal to $1$, no matter which $y$ we started with.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If $x=2^n+1$ and $y=2^n$, then $a=b=1$, but there is no way to determine $n$.

---

It is easy to cook up more examples, if you arrange that you don't need to any "borrowing" (is that the correct English term?) when you do paper and pencil subtraction in base two. When that happens, subtraction gives the same result as XOR, but you cannot recover the positions of the cancelled bits.